# How to catch if any failure happens in Alamofire 4

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I am calling my webservice in this way.

```
public func prepareUrl (baseUrl: String, appendString: String, bindedParams: String, isAuthorized: Bool, method: HTTPMethod, jsonBody: [String:String], callback: @escaping (String) ->Void> Void)
{
    let dm=Datamanager.sharedInstance
    let baseUrl=dm.globalUrl
    let urlString=baseUrl!+appendString as String+bindedParams as String
    print(urlString)
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .downloadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)) { progress in
            print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        }

        .validate { request, response, data in
            // Custom evaluation closure now includes data (allows you to parse data to dig out error messages if necessary)
            return .success


        }

        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
            callback("success")
    }
}
```

But how can I do error handling here. Even If I referred the github Alamofire 4.0 migration I don't have clear idea how to do it.
Please help me.
thanks

Comment: The code as pasted will not compile. There is a missing body in the guard statement.

Comment: sorry I updated the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

In Alamofire gitHub has the method:
You don't need the validate, Alamofire default validation is that 200 to 299 is success, you can get the error from the response.

```
public func prepareUrl (baseUrl: String, appendString: String, bindedParams: String, isAuthorized: Bool, method: HTTPMethod, jsonBody: [String:String], callback: @escaping (String) ->Void> Void)
        {
            let dm=Datamanager.sharedInstance
            let baseUrl=dm.globalUrl
            let urlString=baseUrl!+appendString as String+bindedParams as String
            print(urlString)
            Alamofire.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
                .downloadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)) { progress in
                    print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                }
                .responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        callback("success")
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }

            }
        }
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Comment: I am struggling with where should I put this

Comment: Why you want to validate? Tell me that so i can put the full code.

Comment: If I get any network failure  or HTTP status code became an error code

Comment: @Randi look the answer again